# How to get the URLs of the selected file from the share option to my iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I actually want to expose my iOS application to the share option so that the user can directly open a selected file/image to the app instead of opening the app first and the selecting the file. So how can I do that and how can I get the urls of the selected files in the my application when app is open

NOTE: I manage to expose my app in the share option and whenever user selects the file it opens the application but I don't now about how to get the selected urls so that I can do some action with it.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623112-application) from Apple doc can help you ?

Comment: https://medium.com/macoclock/ios-share-extension-swift-5-1-1606263746b
Will this help you?